# Query about statement in paper on Euler

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I was reading the [following](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.03587.pdf) paper, and was struggling to understand the final part of the proof of Lemma 5.3, where they paraphrase a proof from [this](https://storage.googleapis.com/wzukusers/user-33425553/documents/5b0993445e04cXCmxMD9/Lattice%20theory%20and%20the%20motion.pdf) paper.

In particular, the statement is as follows:
Let $\Omega$ be some bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $\omega \in L^\infty(\Omega)$, and $\psi$ be so that $\Delta \psi =\omega$, and thus $\psi \in C^{1,\beta}$ for any $\beta<1$. Assume further that for a.e. $x,y$, there holds
$$
(\omega(x)-\omega(y))(\psi(x)-\psi(y)) \geq 0
$$
Then there exists $F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ non-decreasing so that $\omega =F(\psi)$.

The proof proceeds by remarking that one can write $\omega =F(\psi)$ for some possibly multivalued relation $F$. To make sure that $F$ is indeed single valued, they assume that the measure of the set $A=\{x:\psi(x)=c\}$ is strictly positive for some $c$, and then claim this implies that the set $A$ must contain a ball. Then they take the Laplacian on this ball and conclude thus that $w(x)=0$ a.e. on the set. They then conclude the proof.

There are two main points I was unsure about. Firstly, the notion that a set of positive Lebesgue measure must contain a ball is false in general, and even if one is talking about level sets of something as nice as a smooth function. Perhaps there is something special about the way these functions arise (e.g. using the monotonicity?) that allows one to conclude it in this case?

Secondly, even if one admits that the level sets of $\psi$ all have zero measure, how does one deduce that $F$ is single valued? In other words, what happens if there are $x\neq y$ so that $\psi(x)=\psi(y)$ but $\omega(x)\neq \omega(y)$? Does one simply pick one value, say $\omega(x)$, and redefine $\omega(y)$ to be equal to $\omega(x)$? This would preserve $\omega$ a.e. if done for one value, but what if there are uncountable many such points? If one had to redefine $\omega$ at every one of them, one could not guarantee that the resulting $\hat{\omega}$ would be equal to the original one a.e.

For what its worth, I belive that these problems do not occur for $\psi \in C^2$, and I will leave a proof below. Perhaps there is some way of extending this to general $\psi$ by some sort of mollification argument. Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

**Proof in the case $\psi \in C^2$:**

Suppose there exist $w(x)<w(y)$ and so that $\psi(x)=\psi(y)=c$. Then, by continuity, for all $z$ close to $y$, it holds $w(x) <w(z)$, and so by monotonicity, $\psi(y)=\psi(x)\leq \psi(z)$. Therefore, $y$ is a local min for $\psi$, and so $D\psi(y)=0$, and $\Delta \psi(y) =\omega(y) \geq 0$. Similarly, $x$ is a local max, and so $\Delta \psi(x)=\omega(x)\leq 0$. Therefore, $\omega$ can take at most three values on the set $\{z:\psi(z)=c\}$, namely one positive, one zero, and one negative. Assume that $w(x)<0$. Then, $x$ is a strict maximum for $\psi$, so in some neighbourhood of $x$, $\psi(z)<\psi(x)$. Let now $g(t)=\psi(tx+(1-t)y)$, and set $t^*=\inf\{t>0:\psi(t)=c  \ and \ \Delta \psi(tx+(1-t)y)\geq 0\}$. Further, set $t_*=\sup\{t<t^*:\psi(t)=c  \ and \ \Delta \psi(tx+(1-t)y)< 0\}$. Both of these are well defined since $g(t_*)$ is a strict maximum. Then, $t_*<t^*$, and this is a contradiction, since for $t$ close to $t_*$, $g(t) <c$, and since $g(t^*)$ is a local min, there must exist at least one $t_0 \in (t_*,t^*)$ so that $g(t_0)=c$. But then this contradicts the definitions of $t_*, t^*$.

Therefore $w(x) \geq 0$, and so it is 0. Similarly we see that $w(y)=0$, so there are no issues of multivaluedness.